# Java Embedded field should be transient or Embeddable should be Serializable

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, sonarqube, sonarlint

My Serializable entity has an @Embedded field and i got a sonar warning: Make "myEmbeddableField" transient or serializable.

What should i do?

Comment: (transient makes b-/rarely sense on "embeddable") -> make it serializable!;)

Comment: "transient" = "won't be stored in db", "serializable" 
 = "flattable"